# log4j in spark doesn't print messages nor appends them to Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-producer-api

I want to use log4j to log business exceptions that happen in my spark streaming process. Although I want to have centralized overview of all my logs (not part of logs on each node in the cluster), I want to send logs to Kafka, and then create Kafka consumer which will aggregate them all together.

I create log4j.properties file and placed it in main/resources. It looks like this:

```
# Kafka Appender
# define appender type
log4j.appender.KafkaAppender=kafka.producer.KafkaLog4jAppender
# brokerList
log4j.appender.KafkaAppender.brokerList= localhost:9092
# set the Kafka topic
log4j.appender.KafkaAppender.topic=logTopic
#define the layout
log4j.appender.KafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#date,  message, \n
log4j.appender.KafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= %d-     %m%n

#console appender
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L %% %m%n

# my custom logging to Kafka and stdout
log4j.logger.kafkaLogger = WARN, console, KafkaAppender

#root logger
log4j.rootCategory = ERROR, console
```

In order to avoid serialization issued, I also did this:

```
@transient lazy val kafkaLogger = org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger("kafkaLogger")`
```

within Object which is Serializable. In the same serializable object are all my methods, which use kafkaLogger.

In the methods, I write kafkaLogger.warn(message), and try to log certain messages, but I do not see them written in console, nor in Kafka.

Any suggestions?

[EDIT] I have realized that my custom log4j.properties is the one which is used (because no messages lower than ERROR are printed, as it is is set in root logger). However, none of the custom messages is printed to the output, neither it is added to Kafka.

I do not know what is the problem

Comment: I guess you run sparkstreaming in a standalone mode on the same machine kafka is running right? If not it's maybe just a bad connection string.

Does this configuration works in a plain java/scala application?

Comment: @TobiSH Yes, on the same machine are spark streaming and kafka. What do you mean by "bad connection string"?

In plain application it prints the messages in the console, but I haven't tried prinint to Kafka. 

What I do to check if messages are there, I run the simple Kafka consumer which prints the messages to the console..

Comment: by saying "bad connection string" I just meant an invalid connection string. If you dont even get your messages on stdout I suggest your log4j config is just not used. Are you sure it can be found on the classpath? Maybe it's a good idea to make it a little more explicit by adding the following commandline paramater: ´-Dlog4j.configuration=file:mylogging.properties´

Comment: my log4j .properties are in src/main/resources..

Do you mean to add last command when I run spark submit command?